# Flask-SQLAlchemy: get column in parent table as child model attribute by one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a example about one-to-many relationship in Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='user')


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')
```

According to [Declaring Models](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/), I can get list of posts of `User U` by `U.posts`. But in constrast, how can I get author's name of `Post P` as an attribute like `P.author_name`, instead of `P.user.name`?

Answer (score 1):

try `P.user`, according to what you defined in your backref

Comment: Exactly I want access to `P.user.name` but do that via `Post` model's attribute like `P.author_name`

Comment: maybe I didn't express what I want clearly, but it's helpful for me to call `P.author_name` instead of `P.user.name`

Comment: `user` is the `Post` model attribute. 

According to the documentation (link in your post):

_So what do backref and lazy mean? backref is a simple way to also declare a new property on the Address class. You can then also use my_address.person to get to the person at that address. lazy defines when SQLAlchemy will load the data from the database_

Answer (score 0):

I can modify the `Post` class by:

```py
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')

    @cached_property
    def author_name(self):
        return self.user.name
```

then, it will see `P.author_name` as `P.user.name`.